# Validate if login happened using requests module in python 2.7

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am trying to login-in into a website using Python requests module.
Website : http://www.way2sms.com/

I use **POST** to submit the form data. Following is the code that is use.

```
import requests as r
URL = "http://www.way2sms.com"
data = {'mobileNo':'###','password':'#####'}  
header={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.42 Safari/537.36'}
sess = r.Session()
x = sess.post(url , data= data , headers = header)
print x.status_code()
```

I don't seem to find a way to validate if the login was successful or not. Also the Response is always 200 whether if I enter the right login details or not.
My whole intention is to login-in and then send text messages using this website(I know that I could have used some API). But I am unable to know if I have logged-in successfully or not.
Also this website uses some kind of **JSESSIONID** (don't know much about that) to maintain the session.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see in the picture, site submit an AJAX request to `www.way2sms.com/re-login` so it would be better to submit your request directly here and then check response (returned content)

Something like this would help:

```
session = requests.Session()
URL = 'http://www.way2sms.com/re-login'
data = {'mobileNo': '94########', 'password': 'pass'} # Make sure to remove '+' from your number
post = session.post(URL, data=data)

if post.text != 'login-reg': # This returned when i did input invalid credentials
    print('Login successful')
else:
    print(post.text)
```

Since i don't have an account there you may also need to check success response

Comment: Getting HTTP Response 500 when I input the correct login details. You can also create an account , its free.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the response object contains the cookie you're looking for, namely `JSESSIONID`.

```
if x.cookies.get('JSESSIONID'):
    print 'Login successful.'
```

Comment: x.cookies['JESSIONID'] does not return anything( infact gives an error). x.cookies will return the JESSIONID whether the login details are OK or not

Comment: It's spelled `JSESSIONID`, not `JESSIONID`.

Comment: Corrected the typo. Getting "success" even if the login details are incorrect

Comment: I see. You'll have to dump all the cookies by printing `x.cookies` to see what cookies besides `JSESSIONID` that the website returns. If nothing besides `JSESSIONID` is returned, it means that all the login information is stored on the server side, and you simply have to scrape the response HTML content to know whether the login was successful or not.

Comment: I have tried doing that as well . But I always get the content of the original website , that is http://www.way2sms.com/ and not the response website that is http://www.way2sms.com/send-sms